# new-dfnsroot target : root target share wasnt found. namespace root target share should exist when creating new namespace

Tags: dns

Trying to create new namespace folder using PowerShell
DFNS Root folder getting below error

new-dfnsroot target : root target share wasnt found. namespace root target share should exist when creating new namespace

Answer (score 0):

Share the path before you create the new namespace folder.

C:\DNSFolder\Home --> Share this folder for everyone